# Mismatch between CxHxS and "total number of sectors"

Tags: gparted, fdisk, sectors

```
Model: ATA ST320LT007-9ZV14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 38913,80,62
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
BIOS cylinder,head,sector geometry: 38913,255,63.  Each cylinder is 8225kB.
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start        End          Type      File system  Flags
 1      0,32,32      35899,54,58  extended
 5      0,65,1       9790,192,1   logical   ext4
 6      9790,224,34  35899,54,58  logical   ext4
 2      35899,54,59  38913,70,4   primary   ntfs         boot


Model: ATA ST320LT007-9ZV14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 625142448s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start       End         Size        Type      File system  Flags
 1      2048s       576720895s  576718848s  extended
 5      4096s       157288447s  157284352s  logical   ext4
 6      157290496s  576720895s  419430400s  logical   ext4
 2      576720896s  625141759s  48420864s   primary   ntfs         boot
```

CxHxS = 38913 x 255 x 63 = 625137345, which is not the same as 625142448s.

The same situation appears on my usb flash drive.
Can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drive is just making up the CHS information for legacy compatibility. Your drive doesn't really have 255 heads. All modern software uses linear sector numbers and ignores the CHS information. You should do the same. The drive only supplies it because it has to. Modern drives don't even have the same number of sectors on each track. It has been this way since 2003 or so when 48-bit [LBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) was introduced.

Comment: It is said that this CHS info is emulated for compatibility.Limited size is okay. But I suggest that there shouldn't be any error.

Comment: The end of /dev/sdb2 is 38913,70,4 which implies there may be 38914 cylinders while CHS total info says 38913.

Comment: There may not be any valid values of CHS that perfectly report the size of the disk. The number of actual sectors per track need not be constant.

Comment: Does the emulation just abstract the CHS from the actual physical structure?

Comment: Generally it divides the number of logical sectors by 255x63 and rounds down to the nearest integer. It then specifies that number of cylinders, 255 heads, and 63 sectors (the maximum number for each of these values). That's exactly what happened in your case. `625,142,448/(255x63)=38,913.3176` and `38,913x(255x63)=625,137,345`. This is the best the drive can do.

Comment: Gotcha! Is that 38913 calculated by the software for "convenience" in other words?

Comment: Yes, as a way to present 625,142,448 sectors to software that was designed to handle drives with fixed numbers of sectors per track and in a way that makes as much of the drive accessible to legacy software that can't support large sector numbers. (So max heads and sectors per track possible is forced.)